# Why is arr[:][np.newaxis].shape = (1, n) instead of (n, 1)?

Tags: python, numpy

The standard use of np.newaxis (or None) is within the index brackets. For example

```
arr = np.arange(4)
print(arr[:,None].shape)
print(arr[None,:].shape)
```

gives

```
(4,1)
(1,4)
```

But I recently saw someone using it as an index in a separate bracket, like so

```
arr = np.arange(4)
print(arr[:][None].shape)
print(arr[None][:].shape)
```

which gives

```
(1,4)
(1,4)
```

To my surprise, both results are the same, even though the newaxis was in the second index position in the first case. Why is arr[:][None].shape not (4,1)?

Comment: Because `[:]` on *any* Numpy array just gives back the same array.

Comment: Each `[...]` is evaluated independently - by a separate `__getitem__()` call.  It's only when you use the tuple index (with the comma) that you control which axis gets which slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `arr[:][np.newaxis]` and `arr[np.newaxis][:]` the indexing is done sequentially, so `arr2 = arr[:][np.newaxis]` is equivalent to:

```
arr_temp = arr[:]
arr2 = arr_temp[np.newaxis]
del arr_temp
```

The same logic applies to ordering the indexing operators the other way round, for `arr2 = arr[np.newaxis][:]`:

```
arr_temp = arr[np.newaxis]
arr2 = arr_temp[:]
del arr_temp
```

Now, to quote https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/arrays.indexing.html:

> Each newaxis object in the selection tuple serves to expand the dimensions of the resulting selection by one unit-length dimension. The added dimension is the position of the newaxis object in the selection tuple.

Since `np.newaxis` is at the first position (there is only one position) in the indexing selection tuple in both `arr[np.newaxis]` and `arr_temp[np.newaxis]`, it will create the new dimension as the first dimension, and thus the resulting shape is `(1, 4)` in both cases.

Comment: In `arr_temp[np.newaxis]`, "Thus, since the np.newaxis is at the first position in [np.newaxis]". That's the crucial part that I am not so convinced about.

Comment: @fountainhead But you _do_ agree that there is only one position in that selection?

Comment: In `arr_temp` (which has shape `(4,)`), there are **two** positions, one on either side of the existing axis of length 4.

Comment: @fountainhead "position" is referring to the position of `np.newaxis` in the indexing operator, it has nothing to do with the array itself.

Comment: What we're trying to explain here is this question -- In  `[np.new_axis]`, since the existing axis does not appear at all to serve as a reference point, **why** is the new axis getting inserted to the **left** of the existing axis, when it could very well have been to the right? I don't see that part being addressed. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: In `arr[np.newaxis]` `np.newaxis` is at position 0 (or 1, if you are a Julia or Matlab aficionado), so it will appear _before_ any other dimension. At least that's how I read the manual, and that is what appears to happen.

Comment: I think I get your drift. The learning for me here is -- the position of the newly inserted axis is not determined by the **relative** position of `np.newaxis` with respect to the other axis indexes. Rather, it is determined by the **absolute** position of `np.newaxis` within the square brackets. And, in `[np.newaxis]`, the absolute position of `np.newaxis` is 0. That to me, seems to be the real explanation of this observation. Corollary -- we should get the same result with `original_arr [np.newaxis]`

Comment: I didn't realize that the indexing is interpreted sequentially in the notation with successive brackets. Also, the documentation is generally too cryptic for me, like when it says "selection tuple", it means the same as what I called an "indexing bracket". Now it is all clear. Thank you

Comment: @Rol The "selection tuple" just has one element, and omits the comma. But I get your sentiment.